# Is it possible to reallocate storage space on a fully utilized VM drive without unmounting said drive?

Tags: partitioning, mount, parted

I created an Ubuntu VM with a little over 12GB of available space on it. I only created one partition allocating all available space (12GB). I was wondering if it were possible to un-allocated any of the fully capped out partition of my dev/sda1 without unmounting and recreating more partitions to allocate this space? My physical hard drive consists of 80GB of free space, but I do not wish to use more of it.

[I tried using the "**parted**" command to see if I could Start and End with some of my already partitioned storage space in dev/sda1 Seemed to only allow me to partition less then 0.1 GB of available space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB07U.png)

[Here is my current usage of /dev/sda1 listed with **df -H** command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNwIh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's impossible to change a disk's partitions while any of the disk's partitions is mounted.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for the quick response.